# Trying to close OkHttp's Response but AutoCloseable interface is missing

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I use **OkHttp** network library for my Android project.

Version in Gradle file: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'`

I had a memory leak issue and I have found that I used incorrectly the lib because I didn't closed the **ResponseBody** object I got from a call.

At [Okhttp's github page there is a doc that clarifies](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html):

*"The response body must be closed."*

It is also gives examples how should I do it (by using **AutoCloseable interface with try's syntax**):

```
 Call call = client.newCall(request);
   try (Response response = call.execute()) {
     ... // Use the response.
   }
```

And also:

*"Both this class (ResponseBody) and Response implement Closeable. Closing a response simply closes its response body."*

**HOWEVER:**

If I try to run this code I got:

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: java.lang.AutoCloseable
>
> Found: com.squareup.okhttp.Response

And as I look up **com.squareup.okhttp.Response**'s implementation IN my project I can clearly see that Response doesn't implement any interface.

**HOWEVER PART2:**

If I look up [Response](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html) at OkHttp's docs there is:

> All Implemented Interfaces: Closeable, AutoCloseable

**SUMMARY:**

Doc says that I can use AutoCloseable but Response class not implementing AutoCloseable.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your jdk version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs you link to are for version 3. Which even has a different package and maven group. Upgrade to version 3.4.1 if you can and see if it fixes your issue.

https://github.com/square/okhttp

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Comment: The VersionChecker plugin said I have the newest Okhttp version. Or maybe it only recognize the major version number and thats why it stopped at 2.x.x.

Thanks.

Comment: The upgrade is a breaking change, so you may not want to do this upgrade if you have a lot of working tested code, or you use other libraries that depend on version 2.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what happening right now :) Lot of modification. It's a must because I must eliminate that leak.

Comment: Can't you just use try { ... } finally { response.close();}. Anyway up to you

Comment: Well I just finished refactoring, Its better to use the up to date lib version but thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange. The javadoc on [this](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) page says it would implement `AutoCloseable` but links this interface to the api of Java6 where it's not found because it's a feature of Java7.
When you look into the code in github of [Response.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Response.java) or [ResponseBody.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ResponseBody.java) then you see that they only implement 'Closeable' but NOT 'AutoCloseable'.